# Missing numpy while running other external python script

Tags: python

I am trying to run a python script from python script.

I tried to run it like this:

```
os.system("python /opt/mycroft/skills/useridentification-skill/speakerIdentificationProgram/scoring.py")
```

Then I tried to import the file like this:

```
import sys
sys.path.append("/opt/mycroft/skills/useridentification-skill/speakerIdentificationProgram")
from scoring import get_id_result
```

they both returned this error:

```
File "/opt/mycroft/skills/useridentification-skill/__init__.py", line 9, in <module>
    from scoring import get_id_result
  File "/opt/mycroft/skills/useridentification-skill/speakerIdentificationProgram/scoring.py", line 2, in <module>
    import numpy
ImportError: No module named 'numpy'
```

Comment: install numpy, use command "pip install numpy" on cmd

Answer (score 2):

just try `pip install numpy` in your terminal. this will remove error

Comment: This assumes pip installs into the correct python interpreter location

Answer (score 1):

I think you are using numpy module in scoring.py but you have not installed numpy in your virtual environment.
Use  "pip install numpy" after activating your virtualenv.

Comment: Which part of the question includes a virtualenv?

Comment: "python /opt/mycroft/skills/useridentification-skill/speakerIdentificationProgram/scoring.py" should be like  "python path to virtualenv /opt/mycroft/skills/useridentification-skill/speakerIdentificationProgram/scoring.py"

Comment: Well, there isn't one there. Please lookup picroft project

Answer (score 0):

I assume you followed this to add skills, if so it should install numpy if the skill actually required it

https://mycroft-ai.gitbook.io/docs/mycroft-technologies/mycroft-core/msm

Ref - https://github.com/MycroftAI/documentation/issues/143

Otherwise, you should be using

```
mycroft-pip install numpy
```

And you should be `source` to activate the mycroft venv, and then use the Python command to run your script

Answer (score -2):

Try,
pip install numpy

it will do the rest.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. Pandas still requires numpy to be available